# Simple.OData.Client + MonoDroid

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, odata

I'm struggling to enable Simple.OData.Client for my MonoDroid app

I'm still fairly green with the Xamarin environment.  I've pulled down Simple.OData.Client from github and trying to add in Simple.OData.Client.Core to my solution

When I do this, solution build fails due to a nuget issue.  Does MonoDroid have nuget support?
Even when I load up the Simple.OData.Client.Tests.Mono solution, I am unable to get the nuget support to function.  I get the messages:

```
C:\Projects\playground.monodroid\ext\Simple.OData.Client\Solutions\.nuget\NuGet.targets(42,9): error : Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can also give consent by setting the environment variable 'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.

C:\Projects\playground.monodroid\ext\Simple.OData.Client\Solutions\.nuget\NuGet.targets(42,9): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Projects\playground.monodroid\ext\Simple.OData.Client\Solutions\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\Projects\playground.monodroid\ext\Simple.OData.Client\Simple.OData.Client.Core\packages.config" -source "" -o "C:\Projects\playground.monodroid\ext\Simple.OData.Client\Solutions\packages"" exited with code 1.


Build failed. MSBuild operation failed
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  I know Xamarin has nuget support in there, but I can't seem to locate it... thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Xamarin Studio. You can install the NuGet Package Management Add-in by following the directions here:

https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin

Comment: Thank you, this brought about NuGet support in Xamarin Studio (you assumed correctly).  Oddly, even after I force a package restore, the above behavior persists.  Options|NuGet|General|Restore Packages is also set to true.  EDIT: fixed itself.  Thank you!